# Code only works if I use the Xdebug extension

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu-16.04, xdebug, php-7

When I started my latest project I learned how to use the xdebug extension and I have been using it ever since.  Now I am ready to spin up a server and go in to production with this project and my site doesn't fully work.  The frontend pages seem to work, which are php based as well, but the backend endpoints that query the database and return some data to the frontend always are returning a 500 status code.  So I attach xdebug and figure out how to run it remotely and the pages all start working without any code changes.  I go in to the php.ini file and turn it back off and the pages continue to work.  Since this is an AWS EC2 server, I delete the instance and create a new one running the same initialization scripts I wrote to install all the software and I get the exact same issue.  The server doesn't work until I follow the xdebug install instructions and restart apache2.  And like before even when I unattach the xdebug extension via the php.ini file, the code continues to work.  Even after the system is rebooted it still continues to work so whatever is being fixed appears to be permanent.

What would building and attaching the xdebug extension, and restarting Apache2, do to the a LAMP stack that would make my code work, even after the extension has been turned off?   My server is being built with scripts that run various apt-get install commands with no binaries provided by me as it all is community provided programs.  Like clockwork it breaks every time I rebuild the machine until I apply the extension.  I can automate that in to my build scripts if I have to, but it is driving me a bit nuts that I don't understand what is happening.

Comment: Have a look at the error log. On Ubuntu by default it's located at `/var/log/apache2/error.log` and you need root to access it. You can run a command like: `sudo tail -f /var/log/apache2/error.log` to open it and keep it open for monitoring. Then reload the page with the error a few times and see what shows up. I would guess like below that you are calling some internal xdebug function that doesn't exist without the extension. That or with xdebug installed it is overwriting some php.ini value for errors and the error always happens you just don't see it.

Comment: Thanks that was very useful for this problem and future problems I am sure.  I need to get better at understanding what logs are available on to me on a Linux server.

Answer (score 2):

When the server sends a 500 error, normally you get an entry to the php_error.log. So first check this file. Maybe there is some difference in memory limits, max. post variables etc.

Comment: This sound like a good idea.  Going to tear down the machine and build another and try this.

Comment: I couldn't find this specific log nor could find a reference to it in the ini file because by default it has to specified setting.  I got the necessary information out of /var/log/apache2/error.log per @jonathan-kuhn comment suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to try to find calls of any xdebug specific functions such as `var_dump()` or any prefixed by `xdebug_` in your code:
https://xdebug.org/docs/all_functions

Comment: `var_dump` is a PHP standard function. [Ref](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php). But otherwise I agree.

Comment: No references to xdebug anywhere in code but was worth a try.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> What would building and attaching the xdebug extension, and restarting Apache2, do to the a LAMP stack that would make my code work, even after the extension has been turned off?

Installing one piece of software can bring with it another. If you `sudo apt install php-xdebug` without php installed, it will install php.

Comment: This is what I am thinking.  I just followed the xdebug instructions they give with you paste in your phpinfo page text in to their install config tool on their site.  It actually involved downloading a tarball and compiling source rather than installing a package through a package manger.  But I have no idea what was going on in the make file.

Comment: The suggestions of others to look at logs found the problem but your suggestion that installing one thing may bring in a necessary dependency was spot on.  My code relies on SimpleXMLElement which is apparently not installed by default (via php7.0-xml) in Ubuntu 16.04 when you install PHP.